# Is the name "JavaScript" an incorrect synonym for "ECMAScript"?

Tags: javascript, browser, web-applications, standards

My understanding is as follows,

- Modern browsers follow the ECMAScript Language Specification
- The name "JavaScript" is a trademark of Oracle Corporation. Used currently by Netscape and Mozilla
- Page 43 of the 2018 ECMAScript specification states,"ECMAScript is based on several originating technologies, the most well-known being JavaScript (Netscape) and JScript (Microsoft)"

The way I was originally taught is that ECMAScript standardizes JavaScript. However based on above, it seems that although ECMAScript heavily borrowed from JavaScript, today "JavaScript" is only a implementation of ECMAScript.

So, by the strictest interpretation, if I were writing code to run across all the different browsers (i.e Chrome/Firefox/Edge), and I were to call it "JavaScript" would I be incorrect?

Does ECMAScript address this in any manner to make the name "JavaScript" an acceptable synonym for ECMAScript?

Comment: In common usage, you can call it JavaScript unless you're referring to specific language features that require a particular version.  For instance, suppose you wanted to use a `Map`, it would be common to refer to ES5 (ECMAScript 5).

Comment: "incorrect" in what way?

Answer (score 0):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#History

Essentially, "JavaScript" was originally written by Brendan Eich in the mid 90's. The name itself evolved out of a marketing partnership between Netscape and Sun Microsystems (creators of Java). It was originally called both Mocha and LiveScript before being renamed to JavaScript.

Microsoft responded shortly after with JScript. JScript was mostly compatible with early JavaScript, except it had different implementations and some names for apis. However there were enough differences with the two implementations that it caused years of headaches for engineers.

These days, ECMAScript is mostly just the standardized descendant of the original JavaScript implementation started by Eich. JScript was abandoned by Microsoft years ago.

So today, "JavaScript" and "ECMAScript" are just interchangeable terms for the same thing.